# "Semaphore must not be currently signaled or in a wait state"

Tags: c++, semaphore, vulkan

I'm learning Vulkan. I wrote a simple program that renders a single 3D mesh object on screen. The problem is i get thousands complaint (for each frame rendered) from a validation layer, saying `"DS(ERROR): object: 0x1 type: 5 location: 9900 msgCode: 373295628: vkAcquireNextImageKHR: Semaphore must not be currently signaled or in a wait state."`
I wrote my code based on the premise that the semaphore that queue submission waits upon, is unsignaled after returning from vkQueueSubmit and is ready for use in the next frame's vkAcquireNextImageKHR. That seems however not to be the case.
Rendering is done without a problem though and i get the image that i want, but i care to fix any inconsistencies that validation layers report.

Answer (score 2):

> I wrote my code based on the premise that the semaphore that queue submission waits upon, is unsignaled after returning from vkQueueSubmit.

No, Your assumption is wrong. Semaphore is unsignaled when the batch of work that signals it is finished and another batch of work, that waits on this semaphore, is started. But this happens in the background, on the hardware. From the application's perspective You don't know when this happens, unless You synchronize Your application with the GPU (either through vkDeviceWaitIdle(), vkQueueWaitIdle() commands or, more preferably, by using fences).

vkQueueSubmit() function returns almost immediately. But You don't know when the batch of submitted work is going to be processed by the hardware. It may be performed immediately or maybe there is some very large submission that is still being processed and Your new submission must wait for it to complete. You just don't know when this happens and You cannot make any assumptions - You need to perform some form of synchronization to be sure.

What's more - it may (and probably will) work most of the time. But there may be a hardware on which the way You do it may not generate correct results. So it is better to fix problems reported by Validation Layers.

Have a look at two code samples from the Vulkan Cookbook: the one about [preparing a single frame of animation](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Library/Source%20Files/09%20Command%20Recording%20and%20Drawing/18%20Preparing%20a%20single%20frame%20of%20animation.cpp) and about [synchronizing presentation of multiple frames](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Library/Source%20Files/09%20Command%20Recording%20and%20Drawing/19%20Increasing%20the%20performance%20through%20increasing%20the%20number%20of%20separately%20rendered%20frames.cpp).

Comment: I have one vkQueueWaitIdle call after presentation, but still it reports the aforementioned error

Comment: @chakmeshma Then try using the fence for this - instead of calling vkQueueWaitIdle(), call vkWaitForFences() and provide the fence that is also provided in the submission which waits for the semaphore. If this doesn't help, then You must have something else missing in Your code.

Comment: @chakmeshma You need to perform layout transitions on swapchain images in order to render into them (color attachment layout) and then to present them (present src layout), and automatic render pass layout transitions are preferable. But this has nothing to do with semaphores.

Comment: A workaround would be to create the semaphore before passing to be signaled and then destroy it after returning from waiting upon it, it works actually and the validation layers do report nothing.

Comment: Allocating semaphores from pools might reduce the overhead of creating semaphore each frame.

Comment: @chakmeshma Having workarounds just to stop Validation Layers from complaining is a really bad idea. And why would You create a semaphore each frame? When a semaphore is unsignaled, it can re-used. You don't have to create new semaphores. You should have several semaphores each associated with a separate frame of animation and then You take the least recently used one. Did You look at the examples in the links I provided?

Comment: I agree that the actual transition from signal-pending to signaled happens asynchronously, but for purposes of API validation a semaphore is always treated as "idle" (never passed to a command that will signal it), "signalled" (last passed to a command that will signal it), or "waiting" (last passed to a command that will wait on it). The only valid transitions are idle->signalled, waiting->signalled, and signalled->waiting. vkQueueWaitIdle doesn't participate in these state transitions and shouldn't affect validation.

Comment: @JesseHall But by using vkQueueWaitIdle() or vkDeviceWaitIdle() functions we make sure that commands submitted to a GPU are finished, fully processed. So after calling these functions we know what is the state of semaphores provided during submission and we can use these functions for validation purposes (maybe we even have to, as all other transitions happen asynchronously and from application's perspective, without additional synchronization, we don't know the current state of semaphores).

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking it through correctly. You can chain asynchronous signal/wait/signal operations on queues as long as there are execution dependencies ensuring that they happen in alternating order. But since vkAcquireNextImageKHR may not be asynchronous, the only way to do that for vkQueueSubmit(wait) -> vkAcquireNextImageKHR(signal) is to have an execution dependency from the wait terminating on the CPU before the call to vkAcquireNextImageKHR.

Answer (score -4):

**This answer is incorrect, see comments**

So you're saying that you have a particular VkSemaphore which you pass to `vkQueueSubmit` in `VkSubmitInfo::pWaitSemaphores`, and then the next thing you do with the semaphore is pass it to `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` as the `semaphore` parameter?

That should be valid and is the intended usage: you should be able to pass the semaphore signaled by `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` and pass it to `vkQueueSubmit` to wait on, and then reuse that semaphore for the same sequence in the next frame.

Glancing at the tip-of-tree validation layer code, it looks like this should work, and you shouldn't get this validation error with that sequence. So either you're doing something else (please clarify!), or the validation layer bug has been fixed, or there's something I'm missing in the validation layer code (please [file a bug](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues)!).

Comment: I disagree. Spec is very clear here: "If semaphore is not VK_NULL_HANDLE, the semaphore must be unsignaled and not have any uncompleted signal or wait operations pending." We don't know what is the state of the semaphore provided both to vkAcquireNextImageKHR() and vkQueueSubmit() functions if we don't synchronize CPU and GPU in any other way (like through WaitIdle() functions or by using a fence). So we cannot provide the same semaphore in the next frame. We must use another semaphore or make sure our application is in sync with GPU work (but usually we don't wont to do that).

Comment: To make things clear - this should work. But it may not work always or not on all platforms. So from the specification's perspective such behavior is invalid and that's why validation layers complain about it.

Comment: I was arguing it was guaranteed, not just that it happened to work. But you're right that it's not guaranteed, because there isn't an execution dependency from the wait occurring from vkQueueSubmit to the signal caused by vkAcquireNextImageKHR.

Comment: If the answer is incorrect, than PLEASE DELETE IT